# Issue with redirect in the Django Application

Tags: python, django, redirect

I am pretty new to Django framework. Kindly apologize my ignorance. I am trying to set the language preference on my web-application using the URL:

WebURL/home?_lang=fr

I am using the following code snippet for the doing the same:

```
 if request.GET.get('_lang'):
        set_the_language_pref(request)
        print("Redirect to same page")
        redirect('/home')
```

However, the `redirect('/home')` does not redirect to the same page. Any idea, if I am missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `redirect('/home/')`.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.